# Get file name and line number for warnings and errors on vizzy flash tracer

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, trace

What's the simplest way to see where warnings and errors come from, on [vizzy](http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/)?

Here's a few instances I see on my *mac*. Quite different from the screenshots we can see [on its wiki](http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/wiki/Features#Explore_Source_Code):

```
Warning: 'flash' has no property 'prototype'
Warning: 'StageVideo' has no property 'prototype'
Warning: 'AsBroadcaster' has no property 'addListener'
Warning: 'AsBroadcaster' has no property 'removeListener'
Warning: 'flash' has no property 'prototype'
Warning: 'flash' has no property 'prototype'
Warning: Ignoring 'secure' attribute in policy file from http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml.  The 'secure' attribute is only permitted in HTTPS and socket policy files.  See http://www.adobe.com/go/strict_policy_files for details.
```

Thanks to the last answer, I can now see [VizzyTrace.swc](http://code.google.com/p/flash-tracer/wiki/VizzyTrace) is required for many vizzy functionality. But *even after considering **all that*** (and enabling debug flag on the FLA, replacing `trace` for `trc`, setting up the "extra options" and adding the SWC) I still see nothing.

Now every `trc` line is  prepended with an almost useless (I can control traces just all right and easily induce where they came from) *file name* and *line number* under Flash Professional's own **output** when I "Test Movie" but not even then will Vizzy show those lines. Not to say after the SWF is compiled and I'm tracing on the browser.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean? There is a possibility to explore stack traces by right clicking on a exception line. This works if you have your swf file compiled with debugging permitted flag turned on.

Answer (score 0):

The warnings and errors you see are internal flash player things, so don't bother about them. you are not able to explore them. What concerns last error (cevure attribute), explore that in Vizzy, check policy log in the bottom right corner.

What concerns VizzyTrace.swc, you should enable that in Vizzy by Extra - Options - Trace Parser - Connect VizzyTrace library. Once done, you would be able to right click (for code snippet) and double click (for opening file) on every line that you trace.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware some of those are flash bugs and trace parser is enabled along with every other option. Maybe I got a bad example there after all. Thing is, for errors and warnings I **never** get any line number or file name. And for now, not even the trace shows up as I explained. Now you're making me believe there's just no simple way to figure them out.